# How do I give same methods to all of the variable in the class in clean pythonic way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

I want to give an ability to perform same method to all of the variable in the class, that is say I have class Dog, with methods double and append

```
class Dog:

    def __init__ (self, height, weight, age):
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.age = age

    def double:
        self.height = height * height

    def append:
        weight = list(weight).append(weight)
```

Let's say I want to let all other variable heigh, weight and age all be able to double and append themselves too. Now, I could do it so that I can right the same method over and over for each of the variable height, weight, age, etc etc. But this doesn't look clean to write out the same method over and over again for each variable and it's even more ridiculous if say I have say 30 variable and needs to define the same method for all of them. What is the clean, pythonic way to do this? Should I put a class inside of a class? Define function?

Comment: U can make the methods to take arguments and update the accordingly. Like `def double(height): self.height = height*height` and `def append(weight): self.weight = list(weight).appenf(weight)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a class for the variables you want to manipulate.
For example:

```
class Parameter:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def double(self):
        self.value = 2*value

    def append(self):
        self.value = list(value).append(value) # I'm not sure what is your intention with this.
```

Then you use it like this:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__ (self, height, weight, age):
        self.height = Parameter(height)
        self.weight = Parameter(weight)
        self.age = Parameter(age)
```

and you access the values like this:

```
dog = Dog(20, 30, 7)
dog.height.value
dog.height.double()
dog.height.append()
```